# Java Scanner to split records by an empty line

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have records formatted the following way:


record 1 line 
record 1 line 
record 1 line 

record 2 line 
record 2 line 
record 2 line 

...

I'd like to use a java Scanner to pull each record's lines out.  However, my patter does not seem to be working correctly.

```
new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^\\s*$"));
```

I get back my input rather then scanner.next() giving me the lines for each record.

Comment: My solution: `new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE));`

I did not set the MULTILINE flag and didn't see it clearly when reading the documentation.

Comment: @Bart It actually produces slightly different output  
It would produce:  
`record 1 line  
record 1 line  
record 1 line`  
The first time next was called and  
`record 2 line  
record 2 line  
record 2 line`  
the second time it was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with was this:
    `new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE));`

This will return the record lines as a group:
    `scanner.next()`
yields:
    `record 1 line 1

    record 1 line 2

    record 1 line 3`
doing it again `scanner.next()`
yields:
    `record 2 line 1

    record 2 line 2

    record 2 line 3`
If you desire just the lines individually, use @bart 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fyou want multiple lines I would try

```
"\\n\\n+"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of guess, but do you really need to use regex here? I think you just need to set the delimiter as a new line char.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if("".equals(line.trim())){
        records.add(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }else{
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(records);
```

I didn't test this so it might have some silly errors.